# .htaccess RewriteRule that doesn't affect regular file requests?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a short URL service for my web app running on Apache. I'm stumped on the .htaccess part of it, where requests like "http://shrt.url/username" and "http://longer.url/username" should ALWAYS call up my forward.php file. BUT I also need regular requests (like requests to images and scripts) to be ignored by the rule.

What does a RewriteRule which calls up forward.php ONLY when there's just 1 `/` & no `.`'s look like? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `What does a RewriteRule which calls up forward.php ONLY when there's just 1 / & no .'s look like?`

Not very clear what are you looking for but may this one should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if not a file    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# URI has one / and no dots then forward to /forward.php internally
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /forward.php?q=$1 [L]
```

#### Reference: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: I thought this would do it but I was wrong - I actually need what's captured by the RewriteRule to be added onto forward.php, so it's `/forward.php?%1 - but I can't figure out where the parenthesis need to be added in the regexp... Can you add parenthesis in so I can grab everything after that first (and only) slash?

Comment: Sure it can be done, see the edited answer. Now inside `/forward.php` you can get the URI value using `$_GET['q']`

Comment: Ah so sorry I forgot to put brackets in condition that's why `$1` was empty. Try it now.

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect now, thanks! And you don't have to apologize when you're helping people out :)